# eclipse Birt and mongodb Atlas

Tags: mongodb, birt

I'm using eclipse Birt report designer, my goal is to connect to a mongodb 4.0 database hosted on Mongodb Atlas.the connection between birt and my local mongodb database works fine.
  **This the URL that i'm using to connect to my database :** `mongodb://[username]:[password]@cluster0-shard-00-00-ndx4i.azure.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-ndx4i.azure.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-ndx4i.azure.mongodb.net:27017/marysis?ssl=true&replicaSet=[replicasetName]&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true.`

**and the error i'm getting is :**

> org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException ;
>           com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "cluster0-shard-00-01-ndx4i.azure.mongodb.net:27017" , "ok" : 0 ,
>   "errmsg" : "user is not allowed to do action [listDatabases] on
>   [admin.]" , "code" : 8000 , "codeName" : "AtlasError"}    at
>   org.eclipse.birt.data.oda.mongodb.impl.MDbConnection.existsDatabase(MDbConnection.java:246)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.birt.data.oda.mongodb.impl.MDbConnection.getMongoDatabase(MDbConnection.java:83)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.birt.data.oda.mongodb.impl.MDbConnection.open(MDbConnection.java:50)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaConnection.open(OdaConnection.java:250)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.profile.OdaConnectionWrapper.open(OdaConnectionWrapper.java:209)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.profile.OdaConnectionWrapper.(OdaConnectionWrapper.java:59)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.profile.OdaConnectionFactory.createConnection(OdaConnectionFactory.java:26)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.design.internal.ui.DataSourceWizardPageCore$1.run(DataSourceWizardPageCore.java:244)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.wizards.ConnectionProfileDetailsPage.testConnection(ConnectionProfileDetailsPage.java:194)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.wizards.ConnectionProfileDetailsPage$2.widgetSelected(ConnectionProfileDetailsPage.java:131)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
>
> at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:832)
>
> at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:808)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.actions.NewDataSourceAction.run(NewDataSourceAction.java:126)
>
> at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:519)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
>
> at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
>
> at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
>
> at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
>
> at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)

**Caused by :**

> `com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" :
>   "cluster0-shard-00-01-ndx4i.azure.mongodb.net:27017" , "ok" : 0 ,
>   "errmsg" : "user is not allowed to do action [listDatabases] on
>   [admin.]" , "code" : 8000 , "codeName" : "AtlasError"}`

```
at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:76)

at com.mongodb.CommandResult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:140)

at com.mongodb.Mongo.getDatabaseNames(Mongo.java:374)

at org.eclipse.birt.data.oda.mongodb.impl.MDbConnection.existsDatabase(MDbConnection.java:242)

... 52 more
```

Comment: It says ""user is not allowed to do action [listDatabases] on [admin.]" It seems, your user doesn't have permission to perform that action

Comment: i don't think that's the issue,because i used the same user to connect to the database  from mongo shell

Comment: I believe you should use mongo+srv:// scheme for Atlas. However I'm getting another error when I use it:
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException: Missing required value in the Database Name property.